# Multiple volumes vs single volumes for SQL Server CHECKDB performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, dbcc-checkdb

We have a ~10TB database with dozens of data files on SQL Server 2017 Enterprise CU21. We're seeing slower CHECKDB performance when all of the files are on a single volume as opposed to multiple volumes. (In both cases, the same high-end (Pure) storage is involved, same VM hosts, same storage network - just different numbers of volumes.)

Is there a documented advantage to spreading data files across multiple volumes, either for DBCC CHECKDB specifically, or for SQL Server generally?

The trace flag 2549 described in [KB 2634571](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2634571/improvements-for-the-dbcc-checkdb-command-may-result-in-faster-perform) tells CHECKDB to treat each database file as if it's on a unique drive. But is there any other official documentation outlining how SQL Server (or CHECKDB specifically) treats IO differently when there are multiple volumes involved?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/a-faster-checkdb-8211-part-ii/ba-p/316882

At the end of this blog Bob Ward says:

> There are also some factors that can affect whether these changes actually help make your execution of CHECKDB faster:
> ...
> Spreading files across disks – As with the general performance of server queries, if we are spreading out our reads across separate physical disks for files, we can achieve better I/O performance.

Comment: Kinda, but that's physical disks. Here I'm just asking about different numbers of logical volumes.

Comment: Hmm. How interesting that it would be faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one is relevant?

[KB2974455](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2974455)

If I'm understanding it correctly, the article describes how the files (named streams prior to 2014) for the CHECKDB hidden internal database snapshot are created using the paths for the database data file(s). If the database has multiple data files spread over multiple volumes, the snapshot files (and hence their IO) are also distributed over the same volumes.

Comment: Not really - it isn't clear that IO throughput is higher on multiple volumes by that alone. Thanks though!